# is method 'send' of 'Transport' in javax/mail/ asynchronous

Tags: java

How can I know if the method 'send' of 'Transport' class defined in javax/mail ( http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/mail/Transport.html) is asynchronous method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most Java methods are synchronous. This method, too. Otherwise it would be mentioned in the documentation. If you are not sure, take a look at the code. E.g. online at

[grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.mail/mail/1.4.1/javax/mail/Transport.java#Transport.send%28javax.mail.Message%29](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.mail/mail/1.4.1/javax/mail/Transport.java#Transport.send%28javax.mail.Message%29)